# How To Reduce Docker Image Size for Next App?

Tags: docker, next.js

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY src/package*.json ./

RUN apk add --update python3 make g++ gcc fftw-dev libc6-compat
RUN apk add --update --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing vips-dev
RUN npm install
RUN npm i sharp

COPY src/. .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/data ./data
COPY src/.env .

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV PORT 3000
ENV NEXT_SHARP_PATH /tmp/node_modules/sharp

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is my dockerfile for nextjs app production. The current image size is 2.2 gb. How can I reduce this ?

I used alpine image but still the final size is too large. Here is the output of  `docker history --human --format "{{.CreatedBy}}: {{.Size}}" nextapp` command. I tried to remove unused dependencies so this is the least size I could get for node_modules.

```
CMD ["npm" "start"]: 0B
EXPOSE map[3000/tcp:{}]: 0B
ENV NEXT_SHARP_PATH=/tmp/node_modules/sharp: 0B
ENV PORT=3000: 0B
ENV NODE_ENV=production: 0B
COPY src/.env . # buildkit: 723B
COPY /app/data ./data # buildkit: 3.85MB
COPY /app/public ./public # buildkit: 1.79MB
COPY /app/package.json ./package.json # buil…: 2.54kB
COPY /app/node_modules ./node_modules # buil…: 1.28GB
COPY /app/.next ./.next # buildkit: 814MB
WORKDIR /app: 0B
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["node"]: 0B
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entry…: 0B
/bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:4d192565a7220e13…: 388B
/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache --virtual .bui…: 7.77MB
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV YARN_VERSION=1.22.19: 0B
/bin/sh -c addgroup -g 1000 node     && addu…: 161MB
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NODE_VERSION=18.17.1: 0B
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]: 0B
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:32ff5e7a78b890996…: 7.34MB
```

Comment: Obvious first question is: which of those directories is eating all that space? Edit your question with the analysis

Comment: I edited my post with docker history command output

Comment: The [next.js deployment manual](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying) says you only need to deploy the contents of the .next directory instead of the full `node_modules` directory. They also link to an [example Dockerfile](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile). That just leaves the question: why is there 814 MB in .next ...

Comment: In order to use only .next folder I have to make a standalone build. And when I do that size of the .next folder becomes 2.55 gb so it increases the total size.

Comment: Do you need an additional build stage that sets `ENV NODE_ENV=production`, then re-runs `RUN npm install`?  That would avoid installing your `devDependencies` at least.

Comment: I modified npm install command as npm install --production but it only reduced the size by 0.08 gb.